# Explanation of $X: (\Omega,\mathscr A,P)→(\mathbb R , \mathscr B',\mu)$

Tags: random-variable, notation

> A random variable $X$ is a function with a finite value so that:
> $X: (\Omega,\mathscr A,P)→(\mathbb R , \mathscr B',\mu)$

I've seen this line but I don't know how to understand it. Can you please explain this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, this is the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Measure-theoretic_definition) of a random variable, namely a function from a probability space to $\mathbb{R}$ that is measurable, i.e., $X^{-1}(\mathcal B)\subset\mathcal A$